# How to create an image generator for combining multiple images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am working on an image generator using HTML5 canvas and jQuery/JS.  What I want to accomplish is the following.

The user can upload 2 or max 3 images (type should be png or jpg) to the canvas. The generated images should always be 1080x1920. If the hart uploads only 2 images, the images are 1080x960. If 3 images are uploaded, the size of each image should be 1080x640.

After they upload 2 or 3 images, the user can click on the download button to get the merged image, with a format of 1080x1920px.

It should make use of html canvas to get this done.

I came up with this:

HTML:

```
 <canvas id="canvas">
        Sorry, canvas not supported
    </canvas><!-- /canvas.offers -->
    <input id="fileInput" type="file" />
<a href="#" class="generate">Generate</a>
```

jQuery:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.height = 400;
canvas.width = 800;


var img1 = loadImage('http://www.shsu.edu/dotAsset/0e829093-971c-4037-9c1b-864a7be1dbe8.png', main);
var img2 = loadImage('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Ikea_logo.svg/266px-Ikea_logo.svg.png', main);

var minImages = 2;
var imagesLoaded = 0;

function main() {
    imagesLoaded += 1;

    if(imagesLoaded >= minImages) {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.save();

        ctx.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);

        // ctx.translate(canvas.height/2,canvas.width/2); // move to the center of the canvas
        // ctx.rotate(270*Math.PI/180); // rotate the canvas to the specified degrees
        // ctx.drawImage(img2,0,canvas.height/2);

        ctx.translate(-canvas.height/2,canvas.width/2); // move to the center of the canvas
        ctx.rotate(90*Math.PI/180); // rotate the canvas to the specified degrees
        ctx.drawImage(img2,-img2.width/2,-img2.width/2);

        ctx.restore(); // restore the unrotated context
    }
}


function loadImage(src, onload) {
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = onload;
    img.src = src;

    console.log(img);
    return img;
}
```

Above code will create the canvas and place both images (that are now hard-coded in JS) to the created canvas. It will rotate 90 degrees, but it will not position to the right corner. Also the second image should be position beside the first one.

How can I do the rotation and positioning of each image side by side?

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8ww1x4eq/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Have a look at the updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ww1x4eq/5/), is that what you wanted?</del>

Have a look here regarding [image rotation](http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-rotate-image-using-javascript-canvas.html)

**[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ww1x4eq/8/), drawing multiple images.**

**Notice:**

1. The save script was just a lazy way to make sure I've got the
   external scripts loaded before I save the merged_image...
2. There is no synchornisation in the sample script, notice that `addToCanvas`
   was called on image loaded event, there could be a race condition
   here (but I doubt it, since the image is loaded to memory on
   client-side)

```js
function addToCanvas(img) {
    // resize canvas to fit the image
    // height should be the max width of the images added, since we rotate -90 degree
    // width is just a sum of all images' height
    canvas.height = max(lastHeight, img.width);
    canvas.width = lastWidth + img.height;
    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    if (lastImage) {
        ctx.drawImage(lastImage, 0, canvas.height - lastImage.height);
    }
    
    ctx.rotate(270 * Math.PI / 180); // rotate the canvas to the specified degrees
    ctx.drawImage(img, -canvas.height, lastWidth);
    
    lastImage = new Image();
    lastImage.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    lastWidth += img.height;
    lastHeight = canvas.height;
    imagesLoaded += 1;
}
```

PS: I've added some script to download the merged image, but it would fail. The error message was: "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported."

I've done a quick Google search and it seemed to be related to Cross-origin resources. I assumed that it wouldn't be an issue with FileReader. <del>I haven't had time to test that so please test it (and please let me know :)</del> **It works with FileReader!**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there also a way to upload more images and that each image will be position after each other, as I mentioned in my question above. I will check for the SecurityError. I let you know if I have the solution for that.

Comment: You will need to save the current canvas as Image and redraw it every time new image was added. I have updated my answer with link. Notes: I'm not sure about the memory and performance but I assumed that it's a resource-hungry process to draw and re-draw image of different types...

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood your question on the merged_image. You want to upload the image, not saving it, don't you? if so, you'll need to send the dataURL to the server in the upload body, not saving it to file...

Comment: I update also my answer. There are some changes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried my updated JSFiddle link? Try choosing some images, and download the merged image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **toDataURL**. But in this way user must do something like **Save image as...**

```
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

And then set for example img **result** src:

```
$("#result").attr("src",img);
```

Comment: Thank you. And what about the image rotation, can you help me with that too?

Answer (score 0):

**Canvas is already an Image.**

The `canvas` and `img` are interchangeable so there is no need to add the risky step of `canvas.toDataURL` which can fail depending on the image source domain. Just treat the canvas as if it were and img and put it in the DOM. Converting to a jpg does not save space (actually a resource hungry operation) as the an img needs to be decoded before it can be displayed.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.height = 400;
canvas.width = 800;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);  // add to the end of the document

// or add it to a containing element
var container = document.getElementById("containerID"); // or use JQuery
if(container !== null){
    container.appendChild(canvas);
}
```