# Fetch Urls and merge into single high quality image (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image-processing

I've currently got a piece of JS that allows me to fetch all the IMG urls inside a certain DIV (vpc-preview). I'm now looking for a solution to take these Urls and merge them into one image that pops up for the user to download.

I'm using this method rather than something like the "HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL" method as I want a high quality image output. I found the Html2canvas method generates a blurry image especially on retina. The original URL's are high quality images which would be ideal if just merged.

**Note:** The images will not have consistent names and there can be anywhere between 5-30 images stacked on top of eachother. Which is why I'm collecting them from the container they reside in as that and the height/width are the only constants.

Below is a Fiddle I've put together to show what I have so far, the only difference is the images will be stacked on top of each other rather than side by side.

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Feedthecreative/nnLzLxbh/5/)

```
function img_find() {
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('#vpc-preview img');
var imgSrcs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);
}

return alert(imgSrcs);
}
```

**UPDATE:**  The following fiddle lets users upload images and then merges them into a single photo for download. Unfortunately my coding skills aren't good enough to manipulate this into using the SRC urls of images within certain DIV and to Merge all the photos on top of each other. [Click here to see thread this came from.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021144/how-to-create-an-image-generator-for-combining-multiple-images)

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Feedthecreative/8kojcaza/4/)

```
function addToCanvas(img) {
// resize canvas to fit the image
// height should be the max width of the images added, since we rotate -90        degree
// width is just a sum of all images' height
canvas.height = max(lastHeight, img.width);
canvas.width = lastWidth + img.height;

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
if (lastImage) {
    ctx.drawImage(lastImage, 0, canvas.height - lastImage.height);
}

ctx.rotate(270 * Math.PI / 180); // rotate the canvas to the specified degrees
ctx.drawImage(img, -canvas.height, lastWidth);

lastImage = new Image();
lastImage.src = canvas.toDataURL();
lastWidth += img.height;
lastHeight = canvas.height;
imagesLoaded += 1;
}
```

Comment: FWIW: the blurry image problem on retina displays is well known. Google that and you can solve with very few issues.

Comment: Hi Tiago, it just seems like a long winded way to go about it. As it involves image scaling etc which isn't necessary when the image SRC's are there readily available in the best quality.