# How to show multiple horizontal images in Bootstrap card?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I place multiple images side by side in a Bootstrap Card?
It should be multiple pictures, but only one title header and description.
In my code, the images start crossing over and intersecting each other.

Eventually, I'd like to use an array of pictures (two or more) and combine them with JavaScript.
The card can be as wide as needed.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="well text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="inn_logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="ccs_logo"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="card" style="width: 50rem;">
  <!--Accordion wrapper-->
  <div class="accordion md-accordion" id="accordionEx" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <!-- Accordion card -->
    <div class="card">
      <div cardcheckbox id="checkboxdiv">
        <input type="checkbox" class="cardcheckbox" id="checkid" align="right" onclick="toggleBoxVisibility()" />
      </div>
      <div class="well text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">Sister Properties:</div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="inn_logo"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="ccs_logo"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Card header -->
      <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne1">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapseOne1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne1">
                        Tree
                    </a>
      </div>
      <!-- Card body -->
      <div id="collapseOne1" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne1" data-parent="#accordionEx">
        <div class="card-body">
          Oak Tree with leaves in grassy picture with sunset
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What goes wrong with the code you've shown? How does what you want differ?

Comment: since you have used `col-md-6` images should come side by side. Can you be more specific about your issue please?

Comment: the images start cross over and intersecting each other, feel free to try out

Comment: eventually when I figure out intersecting images, want to accept any number of pictures from a user, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021144/how-to-create-an-image-generator-for-combining-multiple-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find Bootstrap's `image-fluid` class useful.

> Images in Bootstrap are made responsive with `.img-fluid`.
>   `max-width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` are applied to the image so that it scales with the parent element.
>   [Responsive images](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#responsive-images)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="well text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="inn_logo" class="img-fluid"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="ccs_logo" class="img-fluid"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Here's your second version with the checkbox.
You might consider using `max-width` instead of `width` to keep the card responsive.

```css
.card {
  max-width: 50rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="card">
  <!--Accordion wrapper-->
  <div class="accordion md-accordion" id="accordionEx" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <!-- Accordion card -->
    <div class="card">
      <div cardcheckbox id="checkboxdiv">
        <input type="checkbox" class="cardcheckbox" id="checkid" align="right" onclick="toggleBoxVisibility()" />
      </div>
      <div class="well text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">Sister Properties:</div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="inn_logo" class="img-fluid"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/bOvf94dPRxWu0u3QsPjF_tree.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="ccs_logo" class="img-fluid"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Card header -->
      <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne1">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapseOne1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne1">Tree</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Card body -->
      <div id="collapseOne1" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne1" data-parent="#accordionEx">
        <div class="card-body">
          Oak Tree with leaves in grassy picture with sunset
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's wonderful, only thing is my checkbox disappeared, trying to figure out

Comment: I used your first section of code that doesn't have a checkbox. I've added a second example with your other snippet.