# How to merge multiple uploaded images by using Multi File Upload control?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-canvas

I am trying to merge multiple images while retrieving the images from desk. It was taken from ["How to create an image generator for combining multiple images?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021144/how-to-create-an-image-generator-for-combining-multiple-images). It's working fine if single image is uploaded, but not working in case of multiple images.

#### This is my HTML code

```
<input id="file-input" type="file" name="images[]" multiple maxlength="5" ngf-select="UploadFiles($files)" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif" />
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

#### This is javascript code

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
        var lastImage;
        var lastHeight = 0;
        var lastWidth = 0;
        var imagesLoaded = 0;
    
        function max(a, b) {
            if (a > b)
                return a;
            return b;
        }
    
        function addToCanvas(img) {
            canvas.height = max(lastHeight, img.width);
            canvas.width = lastWidth + img.height;
    
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            if (lastImage) {
                ctx.drawImage(lastImage, 0, canvas.height - lastImage.height);
            }
    
            ctx.rotate(270 * Math.PI / 180); // rotate the canvas to the specified degrees
            ctx.drawImage(img, -canvas.height, lastWidth);
    
            lastImage = new Image();
            lastImage.src = canvas.toDataURL();
            lastWidth += img.height;
            lastHeight = canvas.height;
            imagesLoaded += 1;
        }
    
     $scope.UploadFiles = function (files) {
            $scope.SelectedFiles = files;
            cnt = files.length;
    
            console.log($scope.SelectedFiles);
    
            for (i = 0; i < $scope.SelectedFiles.length; i++) {
                console.log(files[i]);
                var reader = new FileReader();
    
                reader.onload = function (event) {
                    var img = new Image();
    
                    img.onload = function () {
                        addToCanvas(img);
                    }
    
                    img.src = reader.result;
                }
    
    
                reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
            }
        };
```

When I select images from the folder, the console's debugger stops at `img.onload` event, where I am trying to do action in loop.

Comment: You should probably add more code so the issue can be simulated, for instance the definition of `$scope` is not included. You could also setup a jsfiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For loop iteration not working for imageload functions..

```
files.map((file) => {
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = (event) => {
 var img = new Image();
 img.onload = () => 
{
 addToCanvas(img);
}
img.src = reader.result;
 }
 reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 }
)
```